# Why isn't my data being loaded into this UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I'm trying to make an editable section of rows using a UITableView

For some reason, my data does not load into the cell, and remains nil. I have been unable to figure out why, could someone give me some help ?

```
@interface exampleOrderCell : PSTableCell  <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tableData;
@end

@implementation exampleOrderCell
//- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier specifier:(PSSpecifier *)specifier
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{

    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self viewDidLoad];
    self.tableData = [@[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five"] mutableCopy];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ThisCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    NSString *stringToMove = self.tableData[sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.tableData removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.tableData insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}

- (IBAction)startEditing:(id)sender {
    self.editing = YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: Why are you making a table cell a table view delegate and data source? Why does this table cell class have view controller methods?

Comment: @rmaddy i thought i needed them, would you suggest i delete this part ? <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> its from a link i found a couple days ago and ive tried making it work but maybe i used the wrong parts

Comment: Typically your view controller class is the table view's delegate and data source. It makes no sense for a table cell to be the table's delegate or data source. I suggest you read the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451).

Comment: In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ` which might give you nil cell if no such object exists in the reusable-cell queue. Therefore you have to check if cell is nil then allocated new cell

Comment: Check your cell name if you are using "exampleOrderCell" this so in identifier you have to pass  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"exampleOrderCell";